# Increasing memory giving error in VMware ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vmdk

I'm getting this error when I tried to increase the memory of a VM in VMware ESXi

> Failed to reconfigure virtual machine XXX. Unable to access file [VMS] XXX/boot.vmdk

boot.vmdk is already exist but still I'm getting this error.

- VMWARE ESXi version is: 6.7.0 Update 2
- Running DellEMC Customized version of VMware ESXi Image

Comment: Please check if you can access the file from datastore and see if you are seeing any errors in the datastore.

Comment: We already checked it. There are no errors and the guest machine bootup without any issue

Comment: Please check the section 'Corrupt VMDK File' in the KB article [Verifying ESX/ESXi virtual machine files](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003743).

Comment: So, the issue occurs when you edit the VM, not when you try to turn it on? And the only thing you changed is the amount of RAM?

Comment: Is the host standalone or managed by vCenter? Are there any related entries in the event log of the host that might contain more information?

Comment: Correct, the Machine powers up without any issue but when I tried to edit the configuration for RAM I'm getting the error Failed to reconfigure virtual machine XXX. Unable to access file [VMS] XXX/boot.vmdk

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - How can we check the event log of the host?

Comment: VMDK file is proper and boots up the machine without any issue so I don't think it's corrupted

Comment: Monitor -> Events; Tasks could also contain related tasks.

Comment: Yes, We checked in Events and Tasks there are no additional message. Only message showing which I posted "Failed to reconfigure virtual machine XXX. Unable to access file [VMS] XXX/boot.vmdk"

Comment: Well, I'd still check the disk file for corruption (`vmkfstools -x check boot.vmdk`), I've seen some weird behaviour with corrupt VMDK files. If that doesn't show any problems I'd most probably just recreate the VM with the existing disks and the needed amount of memory.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check the disk file for corruption (`vmkfstools -x check boot.vmdk`), I've seen some weird behaviour with corrupt VMDK files.

To that connect via SSH, go to the location of the VM files (`/vmfs/volumes/$volumename/$vmname`) and run the command there.

If that doesn't show any problems you can either edit the .vmx file manually to increase the memory (deregister the VM before you do that and register it again afterwards) or you can recreate the VM with the existing disks and the needed amount of memory.